Deja-dup restoration not responding
I used Deja-Dup to back-up the /home/ folder of a Xubuntu client running Ubuntu 16.04.  The files were saved in an FTP server and I was able to restore files to the client machine, encrypted with a passphrase.
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 on the machine, and attempted to use deja-dup to restore the files.  I connected to the FTP server, found the folder, entered the passphrase, and the application stopped responding.  I then repeated this multiple times to no avail.  I then copied these files to a directory on the local machine, ~/Backup.
I was able to execute the command duplicity list-current-files  file:///home/usr/backup
I executed duplicity restore file:///home/usr/backup /home/
It then ran through the archives - the console output showed '
writing /home/usr/Documents/foo.txt of type reg 
writing /home/usr/Documents/bar of type dir

and was restoring the files to their correct locations in the /home/directory. However, none of those files were written.  I attempted to execute the command a second time and it crashed.
I need to restore these files and folders ASAP.

More data needed. First create a local directory (as you have done) and run Deja-dup in debug mode using the local directory as the source.  'DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1 deja-dup | tail -n 200 > /tmp/deja-dup.log'. Edit your question and add a list of the source directory files and the output of the deja-dup log.
